# how to check if it came to previous fragment via pressing back button

Tags: fragment, back

I am using fragments 1,2,3 and 4. I go from fragment 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 and the same way 3 to 4. Now I want that if I am on fragment 4 and from fragment 4, if I press back button, then I should be notified in fragment 3, that I came from fragment 4 to fragment 3 by pressing back button, and  Now if I came from fragment 4 to fragment 3 by pressing back button, then I want to do something in fragment 3. please help, how can we achieve this.
thanks